# Netty with SSL throws ClosedChannelException when Idle Timeout event occurs

Tags: ssl, netty

When we get an idle timeout event, we close the channel. If we also have ssl enabled at that time we get:

```
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.channelClosed(SslHandler.java:1377)
```

There are some notes at:
https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/305

Is there some sort of cleanup we can do in the idle state handler method `channelIdle` to prevent this? Or should we catch this in the `exceptionCaught` method?

How should we handle this exception in general?

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

How about extend the SSLHandler and override it?

Comment: Override this method in SslHandler should be done with caution to not break things. Better to handle this in an other handler if needed

Answer (score 0):

The exceptions are thrown to basicly tell you that there was some data left to get "flushed". If you don't care you can just have an handler that swollow the exception and thats it.